# Kill state of AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to kill the state of AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin at certain stage?

Background story:
I'm building multi-page form. Decided to use PageView because Stepper's horizontal is broken at the moment, vertical doesn't look nice - user can't see how many more steps is there. Needed to keep the state of each page when navigating, so I went for AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. But I would like for the state to be cleared after user is finished with the "form", in this case, at the end of the PageView.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but the following should work:

If you're using `AutomaticKeepAliveMixin` then you also implemented its `wantKeepAlive` method. Now, you're probably just returning a static `true` value in order to have your state preserved.

Instead of always returning true, you should actually check whether you want to keep the page's state. Whenever this condition changes, you should call `updateKeepAlive` to inform the widget's KeepAlive ancestor that one of its descendants has "changed his mind".

At least, this is what the [documentation for AutomaticKeepAliveMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) suggests to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the overriden method of `wantKeepAlive`, complementing what @Zimes said, you'll want to return a variable that will be updated manually. I for example created this wrapper to make a widget's state live only for 10 seconds. Basically I use a timer to start counting 10 seconds as soon as the state gets initialized. After this period, my local variable _keepAlive, which is inside my state, gets updated to false and instantly after that I call `updateKeepAlive()` and that does the job. Whenever you want to see your widget again, you'll see it will be built again from scratch.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KeepAliveWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const KeepAliveWidget({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<KeepAliveWidget> createState() => _KeepAliveWidgetState();
}

class _KeepAliveWidgetState extends State<KeepAliveWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Timer? _timer;
  bool _keepAlive = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      if (mounted) {
        _keepAlive = false;
        updateKeepAlive();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => _keepAlive;
}
```